# Why does the value of session variable remain even after all the code of destruction?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables, destruction

### login.aspx

```
if (IsPostBack == false)
    {
        //destroy any login information
        Session["password"] = "false";
        Session["login"] = "false";
        Session.Abandon();
        Session.RemoveAll();
    }

    if (TextBox2.Text == main_password)
        {//then he is website server admin

            Session["password"] = "password";
            Session["login"] = "true";
            Response.Redirect("~/TABLE.aspx");

        }
```

### table.aspx

```
    //checking if website server admin
    if ("password" == (string)Session["password"])
    {
        link_logout.Enabled = true;

    }//if ends
    else
    {//not authorized
        Response.Redirect("~/Identify.aspx");
    }//else ends
```

When I click the logout link

- the login page gets loaded, causing destruction of all the session states.
- the login page confirms to that when I use `response.write` to view the values of the session variables.
- when I give user name and password and click login, it redirects to table page.
- when I click logout, it redirects to login page and login page destroys info.

### Problem

- after the login information destroyed, then i click table link it goes to table page, as says NO NO and redirects to login page.
- BUT if I copy paste the url of the table page, then no matter what I do, it allows me view the page. That is it takes the value of the session variable and evalutes to TRUE, even when the values were destroyed.

I can't use asp.net login functions, my limitations do not allow me to use that control.

Comment: Are you sure you are not just seeing a cached version of the page? `Session` does not automatically 'resurrect' values you have removed from it.

Comment: That's a browser issue, not something you can force from the server. Internet Explorer exposes that setting better than the other browsers, but they all have a setting about get new page per request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing a cached version of the page in the browser.

If you press Ctrl+F5, it should go away.

Comment: how do i remove this cahce versioned? any way by c#?

Comment: This is a client-side cache in the browser.  You cannot remove it on the server.  However, you can log off in a postback while staying in the page, so that the browser will see a new version of the page without any content.  Note that this will only help for the last page.

Comment: You can also set No-Cache headers, which the browsers may ignore.

Comment: @SLaks ~ Isn't the "log off in a postback" what I suggested? Making sure we're all on the same page.

Comment: @drachenstern: Doing a server response redirect as you suggested will defeat the purpose.  You need to return actual content in the same page to replace the cached version.  Server.Transfer would help, though.

Answer (score 1):

Make link_logout a linkbutton, put a onclick to the page, and in the onclick remove the session variables. Then do a server response redirect.

Comment: I don't think that will help.

Comment: @SLaks I'm pretty sure of it too, but if he wants to force it to be clear when he clicks the logout button, then instead of relying on the login page to clear it, he should clear it there. Since he can't use the login control.

Comment: thanks, nice idea will use it but prob is as mentioned by @Slaks

Comment: I'm sure it is, but I wanted you to have a foolproof method to make sure the session is cleared too, at least for testing.