# how do i remove the security risk, due to cached version of page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, session-variables, browser-cache

please refer to the link

[why does the value of session variable remain even after all the code of destruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176108/why-does-the-value-of-session-variable-remain-even-after-all-the-code-of-destruct)

in the above the problem is that login function made by me fails, as the browser is displaying the cached version of the page, which also I DO NOT KNOW WHY is capable of performing all the functions for a certain time limit, after which it REALIZES THAT ITS CACHED!!

so,

how to remove the cached version of the website,

OR

how to tell DO NOT MAKE MY COPY IN CACHE!!!

by using c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most you can do is add expires meta tag to the pages that you don't want browser to cache

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="0">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="No-Cache, No-Store">
```

Or alternately in ASP.NET after Page tag add

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="0" Location="none" NoStore="true" %>
```

In code behind for C#

```
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now);
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

For more information refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bh14hk(v=VS.100).aspx

A further detailed article here http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

EDIT: Updated after comments from Alxandr

Comment: You also have the `Cache-Control: No-Cache, No-Store`. That's probably your safest bet. It's the one I've found working in every browser.

Comment: please provide c# way to declare, and what does CoNTENT="0" means?

Comment: Content="0" means that page content will expire immediately after it's loaded and a next time a new request to server will be made - bot these statements are covered in second code snippet. For you - specific operation to not allow client to save anything - only solution is to use SSL. Read the second link in the answer. Most bank sites use SSL and page expiration to guard against these exploits.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're concerned about the cached version of the page on the client side. If this is true you have two primary ways of addressing that concern. You can either add a no-cache attribute to the HTTP Header or in the page's META tags. The HTTP Header approach is the [recommended approach](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#META).

The META Tag Approach

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

The HTTP Header Approach

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate
```

My below cited link will give you a wealth of information on HTTP Headers and META Headers. I recommend you read it to understand the options as well as see example implementations in various languages and HTTP Servers.

Comment: this age is in secs or millisecs?

Answer (score 0):

Donut caching and server side only caching will fix this issue.
In the hole (the donut center) you validate the user's login.  if it invalid perform a redirect 301 to the login page.

Answer (score -1):

The browser WILL make copies of it in cache. Shouting about it won't make it go away. This should not be a security risk unless you are doing dumb things elsewhere. Even if you do have security issues preventing the cache from making copies will not solve the problem.

So: You can prevent the browser from caching, but it is NOT what you want to do. The browser will still save a copy of the web page into the hard drive it just won't try to display it. None of that is a security issue.

Comment: Granted, the site is always stored, but that doesn't mean that you always want to have cache on. Sometime for things to work, cache should be turned of.

Comment: @Alxandr, sure but the OP wants to turn of the cache for security reasons. Thats just plain confused.

Comment: It is a layer of security in the sense that it helps if the client side cache isn't full of sensitive pages lying around on some laptop

Comment: @Harry, sure. But that is not the concern of the OP.