# How do I allow WORD documents (.doc) to be downloaded over HTTPS using IE8?

Tags: asp.net, caching, https, ms-word, download

One of my sites is on HTTPS and includes a document repository which has a lot of Office documents (.doc, .docx, xls, etc...)

We recently found that these may not be downloaded using IE8.  Further research led me to this article.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316431

The resolution states to "remove the no-cache header" which is required by design.  I found the following article describing how to do so:

[how do i remove the security risk, due to cached version of page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176211/how-do-i-remove-the-security-risk-due-to-cached-version-of-page)

Unfortunately, the methods explained have not worked.

Has anyone dealt with this before? I need to **allow for Office documents to be opened/saved over HTTPS using IE8**.  Please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Obviously - the second article explains how to achieve the opposite of what I want.  I've tried `Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);` which did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the cache control in IIS/web.config?  IIS.net has [more info](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache).

Comment: That did it - all I needed to do was set "**Enable content expiration**" to "**Expire after 1 day**" for my site in IIS.  Thanks man!  I didn't need to apply any of the techniques found from my second link in the original question.